# Invalid markup error in vs2013 when adding UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I get a invalid markup error in the design window(WPF application) of Visual Studio 2013(pro, update 3)

PhoneSideModule is the User control I'm adding to the page. I've tried with an empty UserControl but, the problem still occurs.

The page where the UC is added have x:Class="WaSAP_Windows.Windows.MainWorker"

The different namespaces are in the same project and the user control is not in a separate dll.

The problem is triggered with:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:WaSAP_Windows.HelperClases"
```

The solution is to change the statement to:

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:WaSAP_Windows.HelperClases;assembly=WaSAP_Windows"
```

Then the markup error is gone, designer surface works as normal, but then, a build error occurs.

```
The tag 'PhoneSideModule' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WaSAP_Windows.HelperClases;assembly=WaSAP_Windows'.
```

change it back to :

```
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:WaSAP_Windows.HelperClases"
```

And then it builds fine but the invalid markup error is back again. oneSideModule is the User control I'm adding to the page.

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas ensure that your user control contains a parameterless constructor (with a call to "InitializeComponent" as is usually the case). In the past i have experienced that problem when i simply added parameters to my existing parameterless user control constructor.

Comment: There is a constructor without arguments, no overloads